# SQL Error: ORA-04091: table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am getting the 'SQL Error: ORA-04091: table is mutating, trigger/function may not see it" when i am updating the data in the table.

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE STUDENT_DIM (STUD_ID NUMBER,CURR_STUD_NAME VARCHAR2(30),PREV_STUD_NAME VARCHAR2(30), CURR_DOJ DATE, PREV_DOJ DATE, CURRR_DEPT_NAME VARCHAR2(30),PREV_DEPT_NAME VARCHAR2(30));
INSERT INTO STUDENT_DIM(STUD_ID,CURR_STUD_NAME,CURR_DOJ,CURRR_DEPT_NAME) VALUES(1,'VINOTH','01-AUG-2017','CSE');
INSERT INTO STUDENT_DIM(STUD_ID,CURR_STUD_NAME,CURR_DOJ,CURRR_DEPT_NAME) VALUES(2,'SURESH','11-SEP-2017','ECE');
INSERT INTO STUDENT_DIM(STUD_ID,CURR_STUD_NAME,CURR_DOJ,CURRR_DEPT_NAME) VALUES(3,'RAM','01-MAY-2018','IT');
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER STUDENT_DIM_HIST BEFORE UPDATE ON STUDENT_DIM FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
CASE WHEN UPDATING('CURR_STUD_NAME') THEN UPDATE STUDENT_DIM SET PREV_STUD_NAME = :OLD.CURR_STUD_NAME WHERE STUD_ID = :OLD.STUD_ID;
     WHEN UPDATING('CURR_DOJ')       THEN UPDATE STUDENT_DIM SET PREV_DOJ = :OLD.CURR_DOJ WHERE STUD_ID = :OLD.STUD_ID;
     WHEN UPDATING('CURRR_DEPT_NAME') THEN UPDATE STUDENT_DIM SET PREV_DEPT_NAME = :OLD.CURRR_DEPT_NAME WHERE STUD_ID = :OLD.STUD_ID;
END CASE;
END;
```

Update:

```
UPDATE STUDENT_DIM SET CURR_STUD_NAME = 'RAM KUMAR' WHERE STUD_ID = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

The Oracle mutating trigger error occurs when a trigger references the table that owns the trigger, resulting in the "ORA-04091: table name is mutating, trigger/function may not see it." message.

1. Don't use triggers - The best way to avoid the mutating table error is not to use triggers.  While the object-oriented Oracle provides "methods" that are associated with tables, most savvy PL/SQL developers avoid triggers unless absolutely necessary.
2. Use an "after" or "instead of" trigger - If you must use a trigger, it's best to avoid the mutating table error by using an "after" trigger, to avoid the currency issues associated with a mutating table.  For example, using a trigger ":after update on xxx", the original update has completed and the table will not be mutating.
3. Re-work the trigger syntax - Avoid mutating tables with a combination of row-level and statement-level triggers.
4. Use autonomous transactions - You can avoid the mutating table error by marking your trigger as an autonomous transaction, making it independent from the table that calls the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Your trigger tries to reference *the table* that owns the trigger, during manipulation(update) of *the same table*, and the problem raises due to this.

Use some assignments instead, as in the following :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER STUDENT_DIM_HIST BEFORE UPDATE ON STUDENT_DIM FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
CASE WHEN UPDATING('CURR_STUD_NAME')  THEN :NEW.PREV_STUD_NAME := :OLD.CURR_STUD_NAME;
     WHEN UPDATING('CURR_DOJ')        THEN :NEW.PREV_DOJ       := :OLD.CURR_DOJ;
     WHEN UPDATING('CURRR_DEPT_NAME') THEN :NEW.PREV_DEPT_NAME := :OLD.CURRR_DEPT_NAME;
END CASE;
END;
```